# unable to checkout the .htaccess from svn

Tags: svn, .htaccess

I am not able to understand .htaccess behavior.

I have committed .htaccess in the folder but when I checkout on localhost machine,...htaccess do not appear hence my site doesn't work.

I forcefully deleted and checked in again but still no show on local machine !.

I have another branch with the same svn propset and it is working from my previous branch..

Any idea ?? whats wrong?

Req: I would like to checkout the latest code including .htaccess

Any assistance would be great help.

Comment: Do you have SVN setup to ignore .htaccess files? What does `svn propget svn:ignore` give you?

Comment: It return me the prompt with no output

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Since dot-files are hidden by default, are you sure you're listing hidden files in your working copy?
- Do `svn status .htaccess` on the machine where you committed the file and verify that there's no output.  (As opposed to a question mark.)
- Browse the repo directly (such as using the **Repo-browser** of TortoiseSVN and see if the file is present.
- View the commit log and verify that the .htaccess file was added to the repo.